# What is the numerator (supply) when calculating the pool saturation level?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

The pool saturation level is calculated by dividing supply by the K parameter. What exactly constitutes supply in this equation?

We have the following pots of Ada (from the db-sync ada_pots tables):

- UTXO
- Reserves
- Treasury
- Rewards
- Deposits
- Fees

Obviously, reserves are not counted towards available supply but I'm not sure about the rest of these. Intuitively I would guess that only the "stakeable supply" should count leaving only UTXO and rewards but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the formula used here to calculate the *"circulating supply"* from the *UTXOs plus "withdrawable rewards" (rewards minus withdrawals)*. *(You should also find the "withdrawal" table in db-sync.)*

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/blob/831e74b8f19b67bb36ab667609ee2a294551ef44/packages/api-cardano-db-hasura/src/HasuraClient.ts#L122

cardano-graphql exposes it through this query:

```
query adaSupply {
  ada {
    supply {
      circulating
      max
      total
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/blob/f76e944b70c3419ce5c4b56c6a35cdd904afccf0/packages/api-cardano-db-hasura/src/example_queries/ada/adaSupply.graphql

This will currently be 32167734340, and devided by k=500 gives you the current saturation level above ~64M.